# Why is System Monitor not starting?

Tags: 13.10, launcher, system-monitor

I have Ubuntu 13.10 Live disc system and for some reason I can't start the System Monitor at the moment. I know it worked before, some five days ago, and since this is a Live disc system there's no chance in the world that I somehow could have screwed up any system configuration or anything. I boot it with default settings and everything. Since it is a Live disc system I could just reboot and see if it starts working again. But I use it for testing and I have all my programs and everything set up now (I did everything the same way as I did five days ago) and for this reason I refrain from rebooting because I would have to do everything all over again. I am also eager to learn why the hell it is not starting? This is not reliable, a system component or a program (whatever!) that sometimes starts and sometimes it just wont budge. Ridiculous!

This is how I start System Monitor:

- I simply click on the Ubuntu button in the upper left corner to open
  Dash, type in "monitor" and then click on "System Monitor".

What happens when I do that:

- The icon for System Monitor appears on the launcher but no
  application window shows up, and if I click the icon on the launcher
  it doesn't do anything.

I tried to start it from terminal and got following error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gnome-system-monitor

** (gnome-system-monitor:8143): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled
.
```

[image: a]
[image: b]

So what now?... do I enable SELinux? How? Why?

**Update 1 - Installing SELinux**

I found this in Ubuntu [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux).

> SELinux can be enabled in Ubuntu by installing the "selinux"
>   meta-package, which will make the needed changes to the system, and
>   install the Tresys policies for Ubuntu:
>
> sudo apt-get install selinux
>
> After installation, you will be prompted to reboot the system to label
>   and activate SELinux.

Why would I want to install it if it says it's already installed? Are there no instructions for only enabling it? Is there no way of enabling it without installing or re-installing it, and/or rebooting the computer? Is there no method of enabling it without loosing my current open processes and programs and stuff? And if it's already installed, why was it not enabled in the first place?...

Answer (score 2):

Basically the issue is not related with SELinux.
It is due two displays had enabled ie two monitors

Go to System **settings** then go to **displays**

Click on any of **displays** image  then toggle the on off button

choose keep changes on confirmation window

Issue will be solved

The same **issue can be shown for applications like eclipse chrome etc...**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because SELinux really isn't enabled, you need to load the proper modules at boot. If you check this site:
 wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux

It will tell you that SELinux packages are broken in Precise (and I assume later versions) and links to this Debian tutorial instead:
https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux

If you click on Setup on that page there is a a script and instructions for how to enable SELinux on Ubuntu:

> If using Ubuntu, download this _load_selinux_policy script (this is a slightly modified version of the script included in the Ubuntu 'selinux' package), place it in /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/ then run update-initramfs -u (Upstart in Debian loads the SELinux policy automatically, but Upstart in Ubuntu does not. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/595774)